# How do I fix an uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript, 9

I am using Drupal 8.1.8. It is giving me many JavaScript errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'permissionsHash' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'StateModel' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'AuralView' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'KeyboardView' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'RegionView' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'VisualView' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentPath' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentPathIsAdmin' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentQuery' of undefined
```

[image: Core Javascript Errors]

There is no error in my local copy, but it happen when I uploaded in live hosting.

How can I fix this?

Comment: um... lack of information. And should we consider DA a debug service provider?

Comment: What more information I need to provide ?

Comment: Can you try to type `drupalSettings` in browser console to see what's the data contained in the object?

Comment: Just dump one, here is the output:
Object {}
__proto__:Object
__defineGetter__:__defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__:__defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__:__lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__:__lookupSetter__()
constructor:Object()
hasOwnProperty:hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf:isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable:propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString:toLocaleString()
toString:toString()
valueOf:valueOf()
get __proto__:__proto__()
set __proto__:__proto__()

Comment: I can't see it, can you post in the question?

Comment: Can't upload as image. But i don't see the drupalSettings.user object there  and there is interesting thing is that, in my local copy there is not error. but when i uploaded in live hosting, its giving the error
You can see dump and error here: http://www.courseindex.com/

Comment: I found the reason, `<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">` is wrapped by `<em>`. It made Drupal fail to read the data.

Comment: SOLUTION DEC 2017: I was searching for the answer to this issue, and my resolutiong was, in fact, just my `<js-bottom-placeholder>` (at the bottom of the `<body>`) had a `<div>` around it. When i moved it outside the `<div>` wrapper so it was a direct child of the `<body>` tag, the errors were gone!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the properties can be searched and found from the code in Drupal core. And they seems to be the properties of `drupalSettings` object in JS.

This object is initialised in `core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js`.

```js
(function () {

  'use strict';

  // Use direct child elements to harden against XSS exploits when CSP is on.
  var settingsElement = document.querySelector('head > script[type="application/json"][data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json"], body > script[type="application/json"][data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json"]');

  ....
```

This code explained that the `drupalSettings` is contained in

```html
<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">
```

And it must be under `<head>` or `<body>`.

I suspect that your `<script>` tag is wrapped in other element. Please check your template files and remove the wrappers or check if there is a content with missing closing tag.

Comment: I see the 
<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json"> tag is showing below the footer. I think this is added dynamically by Drupal.

Comment: I can find it is wrapped within `<em>` when I inspect the link you provide. It is not under `<footer>`.

Comment: You are right this <em> tag creates lot of other problem. I am not sure from where it is adding. But when i view source I did not find the <em> tag, but when using Chrome Inspector, its showing. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Md.ShafiqHossain I find it... `</em>` is missing in one of the paragraph......

Comment: @Md.ShafiqHossain so it explained why it only happen on live site. Because the data is different, you won't get this problem in your local.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Because the keywords are easily to be searched and found within Drupal core. Maybe it is easy to me but not others. Let me rephrase that.

Comment: I think the <em> tag is coming from custom views of the theme, i guess. Because due to that, site font has changed to Italic. An the js problem arises also, which I did not thought due to that.

Comment: @Md.ShafiqHossain It is very common that there is missing closing tags. I fixed this kind of problems before. It may caused by the trim function in views because it won't help you to append the closing tags correctly.

Comment: thanks for the info. There are lot of custom views, I am not sure where this happened. I need to check one by one. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I've rephrased. Do you think it is not enough? Orz

Comment: Oeps, I had forgotten to refresh this page. Much better ...

Comment: This question is not too broad. In any D8 install, if the footer JS tags are within ANY tag, 11 scripts will die and throw TypeError: Cannot set property... of undefined. Look at your html.html.twig and your page.html.twig templates and make sure you didn't wrap the entire page to the closing </html> page with a div. I ran into this problem using the mmenu JS  flyout library that required the entire page contents to be wrapped in one div. I wrapped the footer JS tags too, and this error killed all JS on the page. So, don't wrap the bottom scripts in anything.

Comment: @JoeHyde The question is too broad because we cannot list all the causes of what the OP is seeing. We cannot debug a site to which we don't have access.

Comment: Sometimes broad questions result in common errors. The common error is the footer JS tags were wrapped in an additional HTML tag. In one commenter's case, it was the <em> tag. In my case, it was a <div>. With the easy access to the theme layer via Twig, I am sure someone is going to run into the problem of  "Don't wrap the Drupal footer JS tags in another HTML tag or all scripts will throw an error." This is a common problem identified by the OP's question. It is not broad at all.

Comment: An opening  < main > tag declared twice triggers the same error for me. Always check your html code with the w3c validator before starting debugging "strange" javascript errors.

Comment: In my case i was having like this

    <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: +1 upvote on answer "I suspect that your <script> tag is wrapped in other element. Please check your template files and remove the wrappers or check if there is a content with missing closing tag." - this helped me fix the Layout Builder for use with my custom theme.

Comment: In my case, following your tip as per your quote Jimmy Ko, and in the case of Kashmiri (+1 upvote to you, too) the `<js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">` in my `html.html.twig` template was inside a `<div></div>` and therefore not directly inside of `<body></body>` / a direct child. So I moved it so that it was directly inside of `<body></body>` / direct child, in actual fact just before the closing `</body>`.  Result: errors gone and Drupal Core Layout Builder fully works. (I'm using Drupal 9.1).

Comment: See also my write up about the same here: https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/2821008#comment-13940093 which has the added benefit of showing how my `html.html.twig` template looks.